# International marketplace payment collection/distribution system guidance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment, payment-processing, marketplace

I'm working on a Marketplace project and I am looking for a simple payment solution that would facilitate transactions made between Buyers and Sellers globally. There will have to be an Escrow system and the payments would go through only after the job has been marked complete.

I have done some research and I am aware of a few solutions available but there are some problems with these. [BalancedPayements](https://www.balancedpayments.com/) look really good but they are US only. [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) Connect is also an option but they do not have an Escrow system.

The basic steps needed are:

- Buyers use their credit cards to put the funds in escrow.
- Sellers start providing their service.  Once the job is done and
  approved by the buyer, the funds are released to the seller (after
  taking a cut for the marketplace itself)

For the level of flexibility I need, this is how I am planning to execute:

- Have some kind of a virtual currency (Let's call it "coins") in place.
- The Buyer pays the platform to buy the coins. example - $100 for 100
  coins. Stripe can be used for this payment acceptance. Now, Since the coins are in our system and our control, we solve the escrow problem and ensure that the buyer has sufficient funds to fund a job.
- And once the job is completed, the coins get transferred to the seller's 
  account.  The seller can now checkout their coins. For this, we can use PayPal.

  Does this Coin system seem like a good idea? Is there something that can be done better?

Comment: I've been looking for these too. As far as I understood Stripe does not provide transactions for banks outside the US (even though they only directly say that in the dev docs)

Comment: And Paypal's dev docs are so incredibly bad.. everyone using paypal is probably looking for alternatives since development is so painfull

Comment: Hi - this is a really interesting question, but a bit outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow works best for specific, technical questions that have a "right" answer... instead you're asking for our opinions. In the past we used to allow opinion-based questions, but they often led to dissension and flame wars and tore apart our community - so we don't do it anymore. So... I'll be voting to close this question. not because it isn't interesting or useful (because we sure need a system like what you're proposing), but because sadly this is not the right place to have the discussion :(

Comment: @TarynEast Right. That makes sense, I don't mind. But yeah it would be great if there would be a place on SO where such questions could be discussed.

Comment: used to be you could take them to the Programmers Stack Exchange, but I think they're starting to refuse them too :P

Comment: @AyrtonSenna did you find any solution..?